# Creating text editor like EDIT on Command Prompt using FreePascal

Tags: editor, dos, pascal, freepascal, fpc

I want to create a texteditor for my DOS program. I want to create it using FreePascal Compiler. Anybody know the logical programming for create it?

Comment: SO is for specific programming/computing issues, not broad "how do I write a program?" questions.

Comment: Are you planning to use punched cards?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure FPC is installed and set up properly (including the PATH), download the main sources if needed. (depends on platform)
2. run "make" in packages/fv/examples/ (in the sources) so that it compiles testapp.pas to testapp.exe
3. run testapp.exe and select File->New, you are now in the editor.
4. Study the testapp source and remove any parts from the program you don't like. A reference book for a Turbo Pascal "Turbo Vision" library (which is very similar to the FPC provided FV library that this demo uses) is a great asset for this.

Comment: thanks ... but that example return message:
testapp.pas(38,2) Fatal: can't open include file platform.inc

Comment: I'm just deleting "{$I platform.inc}",after I compile it... It's so wonderful... thank you.

Comment: or copy platform.inc from fv/src to that dir